# Error with "appropriate loader" during require.context call

Tags: webpack, next.js

I try to get all my images from chosen directory into `require.context` to have later opportunity to load them from require with expression. But unfortunately always on first file error occured:

```
./public/images/image.svg
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
```

This is line in which I call require.context:

```js
 const reqContext = require.context("../public", true, /\.svg$|png/);
```

and my next.config.js

```js
const withImages = require("next-images");
const path = require("path");
module.exports = {
  images: {
    loader: "imgix",
    path: "/",
  },
};

module.exports = withImages();
```

Comment: Try merging your `next.config.js` into a single `module.exports`, e.g. `module.exports = withImages({ images: { loader: "imgix", path: "/" } })`.

Comment: @juliomalves still same error